# Percona xtradb cluster node2 won't start

Tags: percona-server, galera, xtradb-cluster

I have configured Percona Xtradb cluster 5.6. The first node starts fine when bootstrapped, but the second node seems to have an issue with this variable setting:

```
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so
```

I am running the cluster nodes on Ubuntu 14.04. For the error log, this is what is throws at me:

```
150608 18:43:03 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from 
/var/lib/mysql

150608 18:43:03 mysqld_safe Skipping wsrep-recover for empty datadir: 
/var/lib/mysql
150608 18:43:03 mysqld_safe Assigning 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1 
to wsrep_start_position
2015-06-08 18:43:03 0 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead
of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. 
Please use the full name instead.
2015-06-08 18:43:03 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is    
deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see 
documentation for more details).
2015-06-08 18:43:03 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.24-72.2-56-log)  
starting as process 5977 ...
2015-06-08 18:43:03 5977 [Note] WSREP: Read nil XID from storage engines, 
skipping position init
2015-06-08 18:43:03 5977 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library 
'/usr/lib/galera3/libgalera_ssm.so'
2015-06-08 18:43:03 5977 [ERROR] WSREP: wsrep_load(): dlopen():   
/usr/lib/galera3/libgalera_ssm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such 
file or directory
2015-06-08 18:43:03 5977 [ERROR] WSREP:
wsrep_load(/usr/lib/galera3/libgalera_ssm.so) failed: Invalid argument (22). 
Reverting to no provider.
2015-06-08 18:43:03 5977 [Note] WSREP: Read nil XID from storage engines,  
skipping position init
2015-06-08 18:43:03 5977 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library 
'none'
2015-06-08 18:43:03 5977 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-06-08 18:43:03 5977 [Note] WSREP: Service disconnected.
2015-06-08 18:43:04 5977 [Note] WSREP: Some threads may fail to exit.
2015-06-08 18:43:04 5977 [Note] Binlog end
2015-06-08 18:43:04 5977 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

I have tried commenting out #wsrep_provider and starting the node with the following command

```
$sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start --wsrep_provider="/usr/lib/libgalera_ssm.so"
```

But this does not seem to help. The node still fails to start.

The `libgalera_ssm.so` file is actually present on both servers, hence I am kinda confused why it works on one server and not the other. But it is worth pointing out that even node one gives the same error when I try to start it without using `bootstrap-pxc` and just use `/etc/init.d/mysql start`.

Comment: Hi Tom V. Yes, the file is actually present on both server, hence kinda confused why it works on one server and not the other. But it is worth pointing out that even node one gives the same error when i try to start it without using bootstrap-pxc and just use #/etc/init.d/mysql start

Answer (score 1):

The log entries

```
2015-06-08 18:43:03 5977 [ERROR] WSREP: wsrep_load(): dlopen(): /usr/lib/galera3/libgalera_ssm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2015-06-08 18:43:03 5977 [ERROR] WSREP: wsrep_load(/usr/lib/galera3/libgalera_ssm.so) failed: Invalid argument (22). Reverting to no provider.
```

show that MySQL cannot find the file `/usr/lib/galera3/libgalera_ssm.so` so it cannot use it as a WSREP provider.  Check that this file exists and is accessible.  If your system is 64-bit, it might be in `/usr/lib64/`.

Also please post the error message you get when starting the node -- without reading the exact error message it's a shot in the dark.

Comment: Hi dr01. Thank you for your response. The file libgalera_ssm.so exists in the path configured. It actually also exists in the path /usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so and i tried to use this path but got the same error. Here is the error message it displays when trying to start the node: "The server quit without updating PID file (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid)."

Comment: To get rid of this error message, delete the PID and lock files before trying to restart the process: `rm -f /var/lock/subsys/mysql /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`  These are left behind when the daemon does not exit cleanly.

Comment: Those files you specified do not exist on my server. I have myhost.pid and also username.pid files in /var/lib/mysql directory

Comment: You can try to delete these PID files after stopping the server and before starting the server again.  I specified this path because the error message you posted prints that specific location for the PID file: `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`.  This may vary depending on your Linux distro and whether you've configured MySQL differently -- mine is `/var/lib/mysql/mysqld.pid`.

Comment: strangely the file does not exists. Not sure why the error actually points to that location. Can it be that maybe the file needs to be created in that location and the server is currently not finding the file?

Comment: No, it's the server that creates that PID file for the purpose of better identifying the process.  Did you customize your MySQL installation?

Comment: No. All i did was install the percona-xtradb-cluster-5.6 and configre wsrep system variables in the my.cnf

Answer (score -1):

Check the library name:

- /usr/lib/libgalera_ssm.so (wrong)
- /usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so (right)